# Python memory free

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, jupyter-notebook

I want to free some memory, for example, I define a variable:

```
b = 10
id(b)   # it shows 1935260400
```

Then I changed the value of b:

```
b = 11
id(b)  # it shows 1935260432
```

After that, I changed b again:

```
b = 10
id(b)  # it still shows 1935260400,why is it same with first time?
```

Here are the questions, b = 10 at  first time, then b = 11 at second time,why is the id(b) at third time same with the first time?  does the value 10 is still in the memory? How  to free the memory that value 10 takes up?

Answer (score 7):

In python documentation of **plain integer objects** this is explained. Take a look [here](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html). The references for values between -5 and 256 remain the same, so when you change a variable - it actually points to that reference.

If you go beyond that range, you can expect different behavior.

Comment: Moreover, the ids for the plain integer object are consistent (for the same machine at least) between sessions.

Comment: @James why the range -5 to 256?